# Multiple Tables in one View

Tags: c#, sql, razor

I have a model (Model2) which contains a definition for all of my SQL tables. I need to create a view in which I display data from multiple different tables. These are the Models I want to join in one view

HEADER_RECORD.cs

```
namespace BillingApp.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class HEADER_RECORD
{
    public int HRID { get; set; }
    public string TABLE_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string COMPANY { get; set; }
    public string STATE_CODE { get; set; }
    public string BILL_CODE { get; set; }
    public string RECORD_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string MASK_EXTENSION_ID { get; set; }
    public string OVERPAYMENT_LIMIT { get; set; }
    public string UNDERPAYMENT_LIMIT { get; set; }
    public string REFUND_ACTION_OVR { get; set; }
    public string REFUND_ACTION_PAR { get; set; }
    public string REFUND_ACTION_RTN_PRM { get; set; }
    public string REFUND_ACTION_CNC { get; set; }
    public string EFT_PAC_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string EFT_PAC_NOTICE { get; set; }
    public string EFT_PAC_NSF_LIMIT { get; set; }
    public string PREMIUM_ROUNDING { get; set; }
    public string DB_CC_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string NSF_CHECK_LIMIT { get; set; }
    public string NSF_CHECK_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string FIRST_TERM_BILLING { get; set; }
    public string CARRY_DATE_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string ENDORSEMENT_DAYS { get; set; }
    public string DATE_METHOD { get; set; }
    public string RENEWAL_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string DROP_DAYS { get; set; }
    public string MULTI_PAY_IND { get; set; }
    public string MINIMUM_INSTALLMENT { get; set; }
    public string ENDORSEMENT_ACTION { get; set; }
    public string I_OR_S_OPTION_DAYS { get; set; }
    public string S_OPTION_PERCENT { get; set; }
    public string SERVICE_CHARGE_PREPAID { get; set; }
    public string REINSTATE_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string CASH_WITH_APPLICATION { get; set; }
    public string DB_CC_NOTICE { get; set; }
    public string DOWN_PAY_DAYS { get; set; }
    public string MONTH_BY_TERM { get; set; }
    public string LEAD_MONTHS { get; set; }
    public string INITIAL_MONTHS { get; set; }
    public string DB_CC_REJECTS { get; set; }
    public string RETURN_ENDORSEMENT_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string RETURN_SPLIT_OPTION_PERCENT { get; set; }
    public string AUTOMATED_REFUND_DAYS { get; set; }
    public string RENEWAL_OPTION_BILL_PLAN { get; set; }
    public string EFFECTIVE_DATE { get; set; }
    public string MISC_DATA { get; set; }
    public string MISC_DATA2 { get; set; }
}
}
```

HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD.cs

```
public partial class HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD
{
    public int ERID { get; set; }
    public string ETABLE_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string ECOMPANY { get; set; }
    public string ESTATE_CODE { get; set; }
    public string EBILL_CODE { get; set; }
    public string ERECORD_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string EMASK_EXTENSION_ID { get; set; }
    public string OVERPAYMENT_TOLERANCE_PERCENT { get; set; }
    public string UNDERPAYMENT_TOLERANCE_PERCENT { get; set; }
}
}
```

The top of My View (HeaderRecordTable1)

```
@model IEnumerable<BillingApp.Models.HEADER_RECORD>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "TABLE 01 DISPLAY";
Layout = "../Shared/Layout2.cshtml";    
}
@section featured2 {
```

**Update:** I created a class called tbl1join, which has subclasses defining the two tables I want to join. I referenced this class (tbljoin.cs) in the view, however it's no longer recognizing any of the field names I'm calling.
" CS1061: 'BillingApp.Models.tbl1join' does not contain a definition for 'COMPANY' and no extension method 'COMPANY' accepting a first argument of type 'BillingApp.Models.tbl1join' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

tbl1join.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BillingApp.Models
{
public class tbl1join
{
    public partial class HEADER_RECORD
    {
        public int HRID { get; set; }
        public string TABLE_NUMBER { get; set; }
        public string COMPANY { get; set; }
        public string STATE_CODE { get; set; }
        public string BILL_CODE { get; set; }
        public string RECORD_TYPE { get; set; }
        public string MASK_EXTENSION_ID { get; set; }
        public string OVERPAYMENT_LIMIT { get; set; }
        public string UNDERPAYMENT_LIMIT { get; set; }
        public string REFUND_ACTION_OVR { get; set; }
        public string REFUND_ACTION_PAR { get; set; }
        public string REFUND_ACTION_RTN_PRM { get; set; }
        public string REFUND_ACTION_CNC { get; set; }
        public string EFT_PAC_OPTION { get; set; }
        public string EFT_PAC_NOTICE { get; set; }
        public string EFT_PAC_NSF_LIMIT { get; set; }
        public string PREMIUM_ROUNDING { get; set; }
        public string DB_CC_OPTION { get; set; }
        public string NSF_CHECK_LIMIT { get; set; }
        public string NSF_CHECK_OPTION { get; set; }
        public string FIRST_TERM_BILLING { get; set; }
        public string CARRY_DATE_OPTION { get; set; }
        public string ENDORSEMENT_DAYS { get; set; }
        public string DATE_METHOD { get; set; }
        public string RENEWAL_OPTION { get; set; }
        public string DROP_DAYS { get; set; }
        public string MULTI_PAY_IND { get; set; }
        public string MINIMUM_INSTALLMENT { get; set; }
        public string ENDORSEMENT_ACTION { get; set; }
        public string I_OR_S_OPTION_DAYS { get; set; }
        public string S_OPTION_PERCENT { get; set; }
        public string SERVICE_CHARGE_PREPAID { get; set; }
        public string REINSTATE_OPTION { get; set; }
        public string CASH_WITH_APPLICATION { get; set; }
        public string DB_CC_NOTICE { get; set; }
        public string DOWN_PAY_DAYS { get; set; }
        public string MONTH_BY_TERM { get; set; }
        public string LEAD_MONTHS { get; set; }
        public string INITIAL_MONTHS { get; set; }
        public string DB_CC_REJECTS { get; set; }
        public string RETURN_ENDORSEMENT_OPTION { get; set; }
        public string RETURN_SPLIT_OPTION_PERCENT { get; set; }
        public string AUTOMATED_REFUND_DAYS { get; set; }
        public string RENEWAL_OPTION_BILL_PLAN { get; set; }
        public string EFFECTIVE_DATE { get; set; }
        public string MISC_DATA { get; set; }
        public string MISC_DATA2 { get; set; }
    }
     public partial class HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD
{
    public int ERID { get; set; }
    public string ETABLE_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string ECOMPANY { get; set; }
    public string ESTATE_CODE { get; set; }
    public string EBILL_CODE { get; set; }
    public string ERECORD_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string EMASK_EXTENSION_ID { get; set; }
    public string OVERPAYMENT_TOLERANCE_PERCENT { get; set; }
    public string UNDERPAYMENT_TOLERANCE_PERCENT { get; set; }
}
}

}
```

HeaderRecordTable1.cshtml

```
model IEnumerable<BillingApp.Models.tbl1join>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "TABLE 01 DISPLAY";
Layout = "../Shared/Layout2.cshtml";    
}
@section featured2 {
```

**Update:** I now have tbl1join.cs as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BillingApp.Models
{
public class tbl1join
{
    public HEADER_RECORD HeaderRecord { get; set; }
    public HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD ExtensionRecord { get; set; }
}

}
```

In the view I have

```
@model IEnumerable<BillingApp.Models.tbl1join>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "TABLE 01 DISPLAY";
Layout = "../Shared/Layout2.cshtml";    
}
@section featured2 {
```

calling the fields in a foreach

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {         
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p class="one">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HeaderRecord.COMPANY )</p>
        </td>
```

But I'm receiving the following error: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[BillingApp.Models.HEADER_RECORD]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BillingApp.Models.tbl1join]'."

**Update:** Still Experiencing this issue - my controller code is below 
Controller Code:

```
 public ActionResult HeaderRecordTable1()
    {
        {
            return View(db.HEADER_RECORD);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult HeaderExtensionRecord()
    {
        {
            return View(db.HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD);
        }
    }
```

Comment: create a wrapper class which is called ViewModel

Comment: @Dave Show us how you create the model in the controller and pass it to the view.

Comment: I right clicked on the Models folder, clicked Add, selected new class, named it tbl1join.

Comment: @Dave No, Leron means show us the code inside your controller where you  send the model to the view.

Comment: added controller code (BillingController.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Take your HEADER_RECORD and HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD classes out of your tbl1join class. If tbl1join is meant to be your viewmodel, give it the properties it needs and populate them from instances of your HEADER_RECORD and HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD classes. Otherwise, your tbl1join class could also look like this:

```
public class tbl1join
 {
   public HEADER_RECORD HeaderRecord {get;set;}
   public HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD ExtensionRecord {get;set;}
 }
```

Where the HEADER_RECORD and HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD become properties of your viewmodel and not nested classes.

Make sense?

Comment: I changed my tbl1join class to the above and still receive the same error. I think this is because while it's in the Models folder, it's not part of Model2. I'm not sure how to add it after the fact to the model in visual studio 2012.

Comment: tbl1join doesn't have a property called Company. HEADER_RECORD does. If you want access to that property, you'll need to do this: tbl1join.HeaderRecord.Company.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed that problem, although I'm now having a different issue, see update above